# Can't use link path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello i'm new one in ruby on rails. I faced with strange behavior.  I have in my routes

```
get 'diary/add_record', to: 'diary#add'
```

I add link

```
<%= link_to 'Добавить запись', diary_add_record_path, :remote => true, :'data-type' => 'html', :id => 'new-record-link' %>
```

and get this

```
undefined local variable or method `diary_add_record_path'
```

But when i use different route (main diary) it works fine. Can anyone tell me what wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options

i) add a custom route name and use it

```
get 'diary/add_record', to: 'diary#add', :as => add_diary
```

your link becomes

```
<%= link_to 'Добавить запись', add_diary_path, :remote => true, :'data-type' => 'html', :id => 'new-record-link' %>
```

ii) Do rake routes and find out the route rails generated for your path

```
rake routes | grep 'add_record'
```

and use that in your link